# Passing Initiated Class To Function Without Defining Class?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, oop, clang

I'm essentially trying to pass an initiated instance of a class to another class's method, and when I try to `#include` the file with the class (so that I can declare my parameter's type to be that class) I end up with a redefinition error (see below)

```
/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/Source/Utility/Process/Main.cpp:4:7: Redefinition of 'Process'

/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/Main.cpp:1:10: In file included from /Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/    Main.cpp:1:

/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/Header.hpp:9:10: In file included from /Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/    xx:xxxx/./Header.hpp:9:

/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/Source/Utility/Scanner/Main.cpp:1:10: In file included from
/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/./Source/Utility/Scanner/Main.cpp:1:

/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/Source/Utility/Scanner/Header.hpp:10:10: In file included from /Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/    Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/./Source/Utility/Scanner/./Header.hpp:10:

/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/Header.hpp:8:10:'/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/./Source/Utility/    Scanner/../Process/Main.cpp' included multiple times, additional include site here

/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/Source/Utility/Scanner/Header.hpp:10:10:'/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/    xx:xxxx/./Source/Utility/Scanner

/../Process/Main.cpp' included multiple times, additional include site here
/Users/arya/Desktop/Arya/Coding/macOS/xx:xxxx/xx:xxxx/Source/Utility/Process/Main.cpp:4:7: Unguarded header; consider using #ifdef guards or #pragma once
```

**FirstFile.cpp:**

```
#include "./FirstFile.h"
class SomeClass {
    SomeClass() {
        // Do Stuff
    }
}
```

**FirstFile.h:**

```
#ifndef FIRSTFILE_HEADER_HPP
#define FIRSTFILE_HEADER_HPP

#import <iostream>
// import stuff

#endif /* FIRSTFILE_HEADER_HPP */
```

**SecondFile.cpp:**

```
#include "./SecondFile.h"
class SomeClassTwo {
    SomeClassTwo(Someclass * InitializedClass) {
        InitializedClass -> DoSomething()
    }
}
```

**SecondFile.h:**

```
#ifndef SECONDFILE_HEADER_HPP
#define SECONDFILE_HEADER_HPP

#import "./FirstFile.cpp"
// import stuff

#endif /* SECONDFILE_HEADER_HPP */
```

I've tried using header guards but still no luck ;(

I would appreciate any help and let me know if I need to add any more information to this

Comment: Read this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I updated my original post, sorry, I as burnt out when I originally posted this as I had been banging my head on the wall trying to solve this

Comment: @S.M. Just updated the original post, Ive tried using header guards but ive had no luck with them, once again thank you for taking time to help a novice C++ developer out

Comment: You completely misunderstand what header files are used for. I advice to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list Right now please look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305947/why-does-c-need-a-separate-header-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment by S.M. it seems like you misunderstand what header files are for and how they are used.

To properly understand it, there are three concepts you need to know:

- In C++ all symbols needs to be both *declared* and *defined*. The difference is that a declaration tells the compiler that a symbol exists *somewhere*, while the definition is the actual implementation or (indeed) definition of the symbol.
- The C++ compiler doesn't really deal with source files, but with [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). In short a translation unit is a single source file all included header files.
- The build process, which is done in multiple steps:

  1. Edit source and header files
  2. Build source files (translation units) into object files (each object file represents a single translation unit)
  3. Link object files into the final executable

  Most of the work is done by the single compiler frontend program which can hide a lot of the complexities behind all this.

Now back to the header files and how they are used...

Header files are usually used for *declarations* of functions and variables, and the definition of namespaces, structures and classes.

The source files files contain the definition (implementation) of the functions, variables, and structure/class member functions.

You include the needed header files into the source files. Source files should not include other source files. The header files can include other header files, but should not include (or import) any source files.

Then you build the source files separately and link them into the single and final executable program.

---

Some simple example might be needed.

Header file `foo.h`:

```
// Header include guard (to prevent multiple inclusion in a single translation unit)
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

// Define the class Foo
class Foo
{
public:
    // Declare the function hello
    void hello();
};

// End of the header include guard
#endif
```

Source file `foo.cpp`:

```
// Include the header files we need
#include <iostream>
#include "foo.h"

// Define (implement) the member function
void Foo::hello()
{
    std::cout << "Hello from Foo\n";
}
```

Header file `bar.h`:

```
// Header include guard (to prevent multiple inclusion in a single translation unit)
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

// We use the Foo class, so need to include the header file where that class is defined
#include "foo.h"

// Define the class Bar
class Bar
{
public:
    // The Bar default constructor, we define it inline
    Bar()
        : my_foo()    // Constructor initializer list, constructs and initializes the member variables
    {
        // Empty body
    }

    // Declare the function my_hello
    void my_hello();

private:
    Foo my_foo;
};

// End of the header include guard
#endif
```

Source file `bar.cpp`:

```
#include "bar.h"

// Define the function
void Bar::my_hello()
{
    // Call function from other class
    my_foo.hello();
}
```

And to bind it all together, the `main.cpp` file:

```
// We will use the Bar class, so include the header file where it's defined
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
    Bar bar;

    bar.my_hello();
}
```

To build this (assuming macOS and the `clang++` compiler) you can use the following commands in a terminal (assuming the source and header files all in the current directory):

```
$ clang++ -Wall foo.cpp -c
$ clang++ -Wall bar.cpp -c
$ clang++ -Wall main.cpp -c
$ clang++ foo.o bar.o main.o -o my_example_program
```

For the compiler options:

- `-Wall` enable more warnings, which is a good thing
- `-c` tells the compiler frontend program to generate an object file from the translation unit (instead of attempting to create an executable)
- `-o` to name the output file

If you run the program

```
$ ./my_example_program
```

then it should output

```
Hello from Foo
```