# Manipulate behaviour of first ever constructor call from consecutive calls

Tags: c++, mips, openwrt, c++98, gcc4.8

I have to use **C++98** for application i am developing for.

I want to control the behavior of constructor based on if it is a first ever call to constructor or not.
For first ever constructor call, i want to execute some extra code but it must not execute in consecutive calls.
For this I decided to have a static bool that will have default value of false, and after first constructor call, it will be set true for every other call.

```
class data_sender {
private:
    static bool library_initialized;
public: // etc.
};
```

This is kept private because i dont want consumer of this class to manipulate this directly.
Its not const because obviously i want to change it inside constructor.

Now i cannot assign the default value for this, it says c++ forbids this non-const static variable initialization.

I think my approach is wrong here and i should be using some other method.
I am relatively new to c++ so even if you point me to some article or tell me what to search for this.

---

Another strange thing i noticed is, when i define the library_initialized as false within the .h file,

```
class data_sender { .... };
bool data_sender::library_initialized = false;
```

it gives me linker error.

But if i define it inside the data_sender.cpp, it allows me to do this, and compiles without error.

```
data_sender::data_sender() { ... } //constructor definition
bool data_sender::library_initialized = false; // This is inside data_sender.cpp
```

This application is developed for mips and ipq architecture in mind, and will be compiled using gcc 4.8 (openwrt-mips) and gcc 5.2 (openwrt-arm) if that matters.

---

I found one answer on stackoverflow that is similar to mine, why is it required for me to specify this in implementation file only (.cpp) and not in header (.h).

[Static constant string (class member)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563897/static-constant-string-class-member?rq=1)

Comment: *Now i cannot assign the default value for this, it says c++ forbids this non-const static variable initialization.* Do not reword the error message, post the exact compiler error message and the code where the error raises.

Comment: The second question has answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536372/defining-static-members-in-c

Comment: What exactly is your question? It seems like you've already found your answer but are unwilling to accept it.

Comment: @JaMiT yes i found the solution but i am just consfused, why it compiles fine within cpp file but not in .h file. those file are going to be compiled into a single .o file anyways, what if instead of separate .h and .cpp file i wrote whole definition in .h file...

If i remember correctly, university teacher taught me to write all declarations and definition in a single file. But i see modern standards and such always seperate out .h and .cpp files.

Comment: You **have** to use C++98? I cringe when people say they have to use C++11. I started with C++98, I never want to go back. Forcing a developer to use a 23.5 year old version of the language that's full of mistakes and bad practice (now-a-days) would make me want to strangle someone.

Comment: @Casey I work with openwrt and qsdk, they use ancient compilers. gcc 4.8. which has incomplete cpp11 support. I cant do anything even if i wanted to.

Comment: @HarshalGohel *"those file are going to be compiled into a single .o file anyways"* -- this is focused on the compilation step, but the error you got occurred during the **linking** step, when multiple `.o` files are combined into one executable. Don't look just at what happens with this source file (`.cpp`); also look at what happens with your other source files.

Comment: Potentially relevant: [Why have header files and .cpp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889) and [Why does C++ need a separate header file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305947)

Comment: @jamit thanks I got my answer why c++ needs separate header file.