# C++ Order of Classes

Tags: c++, class

Sorry if this was asked before, and if it was, just drop a link. 
I'm fairly new to C++.

I have a project that requires me to create a Twitter-like program; where each User has their own wall, homepage, friends list, inbox, etc. The problem is is that I have to turn in one .cpp file; I have to put all classes on one file. Now since C++ reads from top to bottom, I'm having an issue with creating/referencing other classes because they haven't been defined yet.

For instance, since User contains an object made from my FriendsList class, I have to put FriendsList first, but then there's an issue where I can't make an array that holds User because User hasn't been defined yet.

Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Edit:
How would I go about forward declaration?

```
class FriendsList;
class User()
{
    FriendsList* friends;

    //constructor and other stuff
};
class FriendsList()
{
//stuff
};
```

Would it be like that? Sorry I'm just confused.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of forward declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110096/what-is-the-purpose-of-forward-declaration)

Comment: edited to ask about how I would go about forward declaration.

Comment: Yes, that's how to do forward declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what your saying. It's weird that they make you put everything in one file. So what I would do. is the following.

```
class user{
    string url = "homepage"
    class friendList{
        user currFriend;
        user* nextFriend;
    };
    class wall{
        string status = "empty status";
    };
    class inbox{
        int number_of_messages;
    };
};
```

I also think this website might help.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types

Please message or comment if this help or if it didn't

Comment: I was thinking about doing nested classes, but I've read that it's not preferred. I was just wondering if there was something simpler. But that is a valid option!

Answer (score 0):

Look up 'forward definition'  to solve the problem of two classes depending on each others definition.

But...I don't think that's the solution that really solves your problem.   Consider using `std::list<>` (or `vector<>` or `array<>` or whatever best suits your need) to hold the information you need.    Look up c++ collections, and go from there

```
class user
{
    std::list<user&> m_Friends;
    std::list<std::string> m_Messages;
    std::list<std::string> m_Wall;
};
```

Comment: Even if he uses a vector, doesn't he still need a forward declaration? If `User` contains `vector<FriendsLIst>` and `FriendsList` contains `vector<User>`, you still have a circular dependency.

Comment: You don't need the class FriendsList at all.  That's literally what the `list<user&> m_Friends` is.

Comment: But maybe he has other methods he wants to define for the `FriendsList` class.

Answer (score 0):

Forward declaration was the way to go for most of my issues. Thanks for the help and tips about other alternatives!