# Avoid multiple include from the same project

Tags: c++

I have a project as it:

> `main.cpp`
> `TaskManager.cpp`
> `Web.cpp` (Use `HTTPRequest.hpp` LIB)

I'm using `main.cpp` for simple web request, however `TaskManager` is really big in size, which is why it is in a different file.

`TaskManager` need to send web request (like `main.cpp` does) but when I tried to use

```
#include "Web.cpp"
```

inside `TaskManager.cpp`, 60+ errors pops out, obviously I realize this is because `Web.cpp` is already called inside `main.cpp`.

But I don't know what to do to be able to use the same functions as `Web.cpp` from different files.

Comment: you should not include a source file, not once

Comment: What do you mean ? You are say i shiould not use the HTTPRequest.cpp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When importing code from other file into a "main" file, we use something called a **header** file (`.h`). Never include a `.cpp` directly.

For example, you have a file containing some function like this

```
//test.cpp
int add(int x, int y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

So you can create a header file called `test.h`:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

int add(int x, int y);

#endif
```

And include it to your main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h" // Insert contents of test.h at this point
 
int main()
{
    std::cout << "The sum of 3 and 4 is " << add(3, 4) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

`#ifndef` and `#define` call is called a **header guard**. It prevents conflict from importing multiple files (which is what you want).

Other advantages of header files: [What are the benefits and drawbacks of using header files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798202/what-are-the-benefits-and-drawbacks-of-using-header-files)

More info:

- [Why have header files and .cpp files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333889/why-have-header-files-and-cpp-files)
- [Why should I not include cpp files and instead use a header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686204/why-should-i-not-include-cpp-files-and-instead-use-a-header)
- [Some documentation about header files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/header-files-cpp#:%7E:text=To%20minimize%20the%20potential%20for,file%20that%20requires%20that%20declaration.).